# Member type coercion of a TypeScript interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a TypeScript interface to describe data loaded from a REST API. It looks like this:

```
interface Project  {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  status: string;
  description: string;
  projecttype: string; 
  startdate: string;
  enddate: string;
  testingtype: string;
  projectexception: string;
  companyname: string;
  owner: string; 
};
```

Loading data looks like this.

```
 const projectData = await fetchProject(id) as Project;
```

I use `projectData` to populate the form. However, React throws a warning if an input value is set to `null`

I discovered that for some reason `Project` doesn't coerce null values to string, so if I `console.log(projectData)`, I get something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "status": "Completed",
    "name": "Name of project",
    "description": "The project is about X, Y and Z",
    "projecttype": "A cool type of project",
    "startdate": "2021-10-26",
    "enddate": "2021-10-31",
    "testingtype": "My Testing Type",
    "projectexception": null,
    "companyname": "Microsoft",
    "owner": "admin"
}
```

`projectexception` is shown as null when it should be an empty string.

I thought about converting all instances of `value={projectData.varname}` to `value={String(projectData.varname)}` but I'm wondering if there might be a cleaner way to coerce the values when the data is loaded?

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `fetchProject`?

Comment: `as` **is not a cast**. "Casts" don't exist in TypeScript. `as` = **as**sertion. You are telling the compiler that you know better and that it is a `Project`. Unfortunately, that isn't the case here. You'll have to write the "cast" yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> `projectexception` is shown as null when it should be an empty string.

> I thought about converting all instances of `value={projectData.varname}` to `value={String(projectData.varname)}`

`String(null)` will not produce an empty string, but will evaluate to the literal string `"null"`:

```js
const result = String(null);

console.log({ result }); // { result: "null" }
```

> but I'm wondering if there might be a cleaner way to coerce the values when the data is loaded?

"Cleaner" is not something that can be answered objectively. Any approach will require manual conversion of the `null` values to empty strings in order to have a data structure that conforms to your expectations. Using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) only affects the type system, not program values.

You can create a functional abstraction that will perform the conversion for you:

```ts
type NullToEmptyString<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: null extends T[K]
    ? Exclude<T[K], null> | ""
    : T[K];
};

function copyAndConvertNullToEmptyString<
  T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>,
>(input: T): NullToEmptyString<T> {
  const output = {} as NullToEmptyString<T>;
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(input)) {
    output[key] = value === null ? "" : value;
  }
  return output;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```ts
type DataReceived = {
  a?: number;
  b: string;
  c: string | null;
  d: boolean;
  // etc.
};

type DataDesired = {
  a?: number;
  b: string;
  c: string;
  d: boolean;
  // etc.
};

function getData(): DataReceived {
  return {
    a: 1,
    b: "foo",
    c: null,
    d: true,
  };
}

const actual = copyAndConvertNullToEmptyString(getData()) satisfies DataDesired;

const expected = {
  a: 1,
  b: "foo",
  c: "",
  d: true,
};

console.log(
  [
    ...Object.keys(actual),
    ...Object.keys(expected),
  ].every((k) => actual[k] === expected[k]),
); // true
```

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgGwQFQPYFEC2ZQGVgBOAlgHYDmAPMgHxQC8UA3gFBRQDaA0lKVANYQQqAGZRkAXQBcUEogRQIAD2AQSAEwDOYruNZsoAfijpFAYwRw1EKjoA0MubQA+UAESu9bach0BuZgC+-szCcCSmwESoJFCmqGAgAILqAMLRAG4QBMDwSGhYOCD4xOQUesgKyqqaUABKEHEEahQACgTxWaCcgvZhfCSoAO4k1LbM1AAUpGBwwN4AlNK5KBjYeISklDRMenEkGsBQqLMzhwyMAVAAhlrL+WtFG6U0-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)

Compiled JS from the playground:

```js
function copyAndConvertNullToEmptyString(input) {
  const output = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(input)) {
    output[key] = value === null ? "" : value;
  }
  return output;
}

function getData() {
  return {
    a: 1,
    b: "foo",
    c: null,
    d: true,
  };
}

const actual = copyAndConvertNullToEmptyString(getData());

const expected = {
  a: 1,
  b: "foo",
  c: "",
  d: true,
};

console.log({ actual, expected });

console.log([
  ...Object.keys(actual),
  ...Object.keys(expected),
].every((k) => actual[k] === expected[k]));
```